# Simplify PyreResponse iteration

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

Here's my code:

```
lastRow = db.child("twitter-search").order_by_key().limit_to_last(1).get(user['idToken'])

latestId = None

for row in lastRow.each():
for key, value in row.val().items():
    if key == "latest_id":
        latestId = value
```

It is working but is there anyway to make it shorter?

Comment: you can assign as : latestId = row.val()["latest_id"] instead of iterating through row every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`O(1)` to check whether key exists or not, update `latestId` if it does.

```
latestId = None
for row in lastRow.each():
    if "latest_id" in row:
        latestId = row["latest_id"]
```